# How to check why QOpenGLVertexArrayObject::create fails

Tags: qt, opengl

I have got the following code for creating a VAO :

```
// VAO
mVAO = new QOpenGLVertexArrayObject();
if (!mVAO->create()) {
    qDebug() << "ERROR: VAO creation failed";
}
mVAO->bind();

// VBO
mVBO = new QOpenGLBuffer(QOpenGLBuffer::VertexBuffer);
if (!mVBO->create()) {
    qDebug() << "ERROR: VBO creation failed";
}
mVBO->setUsagePattern( QOpenGLBuffer::StreamDraw );
mVBO->bind();
mVBO->allocate( mVertices.constData(), mVertices.count() * 3 * sizeof( float ) );
mProgram.enableAttributeArray(mVertexAttrLoc);
mProgram.setAttributeBuffer(mVertexAttrLoc, GL_FLOAT, 0, 3 ); // uses the currently bound VBO

// This is imp, we do not want any more state info recorded
mVAO->release();
```

mVAO->create() fails in the above code. But the VBO creation does not fail. I am not sure how to find out a more detailed reason as to why the VAO creation fails.

One other thing is I am using Qt 5.2 and a laptop with a dual video card and the nvidia optimus  thingy. But I can see the program is executed by the nvidia card and not the onboard intel card. So it probably is not a hardware capabilities issue.

The OpenGL version reported by 
    qDebug() << "OpenGL version:" << QGLFormat::openGLVersionFlags();

is OpenGL version: QFlags(0x800) which is QGLFormat::OpenGL_ES_Version_2_0

Maybe the ES version is whats standard in laptops ?

I used this as a reference to write the code : http://www.kdab.com/opengl-in-qt-5-1-part-2/

Comment: Well, for one thing OpenGL ES 2.0 does not have Vertex Array Objects. VAOs exist in extension form that some ES 2.0 implementations may implement, but it is was not made core until ES 3.0. As for ES being standard in laptops, that is not even remotely true. It is standard in embedded devices like cell phones and tablets, but laptops generally use lower-power versions of desktop GPUs and traditional GL.

Comment: Which OS are you using? If Windows, is that an ANGLE (ES2) or a Desktop GL build? Can you also dump the extension list of that context? (I suspect: ANGLE on Windows, which would explain both why you have an ES2 context, as well as the lack of the `OES_vertex_array_object` extension).